# laravel 4 routing, models, controllers error Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ ModelNotFoundException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am learning laravel 4 and decided to work through a course on tutsplus called The MVC Mindset and finished up Models and Scoping tut found here https://tutsplus.com/course/the-mvc-mindset-2/. I got a error when trying to view the create.blade.php file. I get this error below.

trying to see where I went wrong as I was able to apply CRUD on this page before but when I put in the search query aspect it caused all these erros.

Hoping someone can help!!

```
Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ ModelNotFoundException. 

open: C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php
* @param array $columns
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|Collection|static
*/
public static function findOrFail($id, $columns = array('*'))
{
if ( ! is_null($model = static::find($id, $columns))) return $model;
throw new ModelNotFoundException;
}
```

Here is the create.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Create</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/names">
<label for="name">Name to add:</label>
<input name="name" id="name" type="text">
<div>
<button type="submit">Submit</button> 
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the index.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>All Names</h1>

<p> <a href="/names/create">Add a New name</a></p>

<ul>
@foreach ($folks as $person)
<li> 
<a href="names/{{$person->id}}">
{{ $person->name }} 
</a>
</li>
@endforeach
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the routes.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
|
*/

//Route::get('/', function()
//{
// return View::make('hello');
//});
//Route::get('names/search/{letter}', function($letter)
//{
// return Person::byFirstLetter($letter)->get();
// //return Person::where('name','LIKE', "$query%")->get();
//});

Route::get('names/{id}', 'NamesController@getShow');
Route::controller('names', 'NamesController');
```

Here is the NamesController.php

```
<?php

class NamesController extends BaseController {

public function getIndex()
{
$folks = Person::all();

return View::make('names.index')
->with('folks', $folks);
}

public function postIndex()
{
$name = Input::get('name');

Person::create(['name' => $name]);

return Redirect::to('/names');
}

public function getShow($id)
{
$person = Person::findOrFail($id);
//old way without using models
//$person = DB::table('people')->find($id);
//if (null == $person) return Redirect::to('names');

return $person->name;
}

public function getCreate()
{
return View::make('names.create');
}


}
```

Here is the Person.php

```
<?php

class Person extends Eloquent {

//protected $guarded= array();
protected $guarded=[];

public $timestamps = false;

public function scopeByFirstLetter($query, $letter)
{

return $query->where('name','LIKE', "$letter%");

}

}
```

Comment: Looking at the error and your code, looks like you're not hitting /names/create, but /names/<SomeOtherId> and this <SomeOtherId> is not being found. Are you sure you you have this id on database?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try mentioning the `$table` property on the model?

```
class Person extends Eloquent {
    protected $table ='TABLE_NAME_GOES_HERE';
}
```

As per the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#basic-usage)

> The lower-case, plural name of the class will be used as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified. So, in this case, Eloquent will assume the User model stores records in the users table. You may specify a custom table by defining a table property on your model

So ensure you have your table name as mentioned in the documentation. Else specify the `table` property. Since your Model is `Person` it will look for the table `persons`. Ensure you have this on your database.